# read params of int variable in ida?

Tags: ida

I have located a known int variable that belongs to a tls library, the variable has parameters I need to look at to find the name of another variable I need. Is it possible to read the parameters?

[image]

Comment: [`mbedtls_ecdh_read_params`](https://siliconlabs.github.io/Gecko_SDK_Doc/mbedtls/html/ecdh_8h.html#af07326ad0017bf6fcfb9f93e43641254) is not a variable but a function. You first need to locate its code inside of the binary, it could also be loaded from a DLL

Comment: "`int` variables" don't have parameters, so you can't read them, because they don't exist.

Comment: @mimak wdym its code, i thought the code would be where the definition of the function would hold the parameters

Comment: @Botytec that's exactly what you should find and debug to read the parameter values

Comment: @mimak do you think what i sent is the definition of the function?

Comment: No it's not, it's string with the function's name